# How to detect feedback on motor

Tags: arduino, dc-motor

In my Arduino project, a 3v 50RPM DC Motor starts to rotate an independent mechanical knob. When the mechanical knob reaches its zero point, it gets locked. How can I get this lock feedback so I can stop rotating the motor and avoid damage to the motor?

Comment: To "get" the feedback, someone has to *provide* it. Do you have anything sensing the lock? Or at least the motor current?

Comment: Can you monitor current going to the motor?

Comment: I guess I can figure out how to read the current going to the motor

Comment: In this case the "feedback" would be the increased current.

Comment: 'Sensing the lock' is the part I am tryng to figure out

Comment: This is not what you asked about.

Comment: How are you controlling the motor? Arduino -> Something? -> Motor?

Comment: Using PN2222 Transistor, 1N4001 diode & 270 Ω Resistor as explained [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-13-dc-motors/breadboard-layout).

Answer (score 1):

Measure the collector voltage. When the lock engages the apparent motor resistance will drop, current will rise, and so will the collector voltage. Of course, this assumes that the motor current rise does not pull down the Arduino 5 volts too much.

Note also that, once you turn off the transistor, the collector voltage will rise to 5 volts. Dealing with that is a software issue, and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

A electromechanical solution is also possible. 
Make a contact that opens the electric connection when the motor runs against the lock making the motor stop. By putting a reverse diode over the same  contact the motor can run when the supply is reversed so you can unlock the system also.

Comment: Knob/Locking mechanism is independent and I do not have access to it.